# Why Hbase called as schema less?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

I'm newbie to HBase. Actually HBase called schemaless Data store. 
But to store values in particular column, we should need to specify the table and then column family then column name then the {Actual value}.

So I confused that, To put values into a hbase table why should we need to specify column names at all.

Is HBase is schemaless or not?

Please clarify my doubt?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: People who downvoted this question should be ashamed. 
The question is very sensible and totally makes sense.

Comment: Look at the resembeleance between Schemaless, shameless... just for fun :)

Answer (score 7):

I've used the term "flexible schema" instead of schemaless, but that's nuance.

What this really means is that the "schema" is stored with the record, not the table. In a RDBMS, the schema is defined and that table has the schema. In HBase (and other BigTable implementations) data is labeled with its types.

An analogy is CSV : RDBMS is to XML : HBase. In CSV, you have an assumption on what a column is. In XML, you specify exactly what it is.

Comment: I'm looking for a more detailed question, then. You asked a yes or no question and I went way above and beyond already.